# Cannot persist List using JPA

Tags: jpa, openjpa

I’m trying to persist the following type of object using JPA to a database:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Map<String, List<String>> parameters;
```

It seems like it should work, but when I run the program I get:

```
openjpa.MetaData - OpenJPA cannot map field <package.classname>.parameters efficiently.  It is of an unsupported type. The field value will be serialized to a BLOB by default.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What is in the map and are there generics defining the type?

Comment: @Chris A cleansed version:
<parameters>
  <field name="one">
    <value>one</value>
    <value>two</value>
    <value>three</value>
  </field>
  <field name="two">value2</field>
</parameters>

Comment: The element collection works for a collection, while you seem to be trying to map a collection of collections - a map of lists.  JPA expects a basic or object type instead of the list, forcing it to be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I meant to answer my own question a while back and now I no longer have access to run the program.  I *think* this was our solution:
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private List parameters = new ArrayList();